# Is there any way to show validation error summary in AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am using B2C custom policies, in my signup page i need to show validation summary in the top of the page like the below image. Is that possible.

[image: validation summary]

Answer (score 0):

You have to [enable Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#prerequisites) for your policies and use [custom page content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#custom-page-content-walkthrough).

Recommended: Add a validation summary div before the api div (where B2C renders its content):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Product Brand Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="validationSummary"></div>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And display your validation summary using [vanilla javascript](https://www.codementor.io/@robertwozniak/form-validation-system-in-vanilla-javascript-oldy425jc) or [jQuery](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) results.